# Machine Learning & Image Recognition: How to start?

Tags: machine-learning, image-classification, image-recognition

I've been a full stack web developer for 15 years now and would like to be involved in machine learning. There is already a specific scenario for this: We have a database with several million products and one product image each. There is also a database with about 5000 terms.

A product image is linked to several terms (usually 3 - 20), whereby the link still has a weighting (1-100%). The terms are always of a visual nature, that is, they describe a visually recognizable feature on the image.

The aim should now be to upload a new image (of course with thematic reference) and to get an answer with possible terms (including probability) based on the already classified images.

Do you have any advice on how best to start here? Is there a framework that comes close to this scenario? Is TensorFlow relevant for this task? What new language should I learn?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome Aboard, From your case it seems that you need a model that's pretrained on your dataset and then you can use it (after saving the weights and all) to keep on predicting via the get and the post request to a server

Comment: Hey @Aditya, that's totally right! Do you have a hint which are the right tools to use?

Comment: Py, TF is nice but it's a bit subtle , Keras is much more easier and more Pythonic, plus I guess django is also needed, You will be building your own model(CNN based), so it's better to start with easier stuffs and you can scale very fast given your prior experience...

Comment: You may want to consider transfer learning (e.g. XCeption pre- trained on imagenet), just with a different output (e.g. multi label with softmax activation). You could do it in many languages/NN packages, but one obvious starting point is keras in python. There's plenty of tutorials for that and a book by the author of keras (Chollet) with a chapter that describes something quite close to what you need.